# Distinct Values in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Hello Friends I am using the following query :

```
$cur_date = date('Y-m-d');
   $clientTemp = DB::table('clients')->where('quotations.exp_date','<',$cur_date)
     ->join('quotations','quotations.customer_id','=','clients.id')
      ->get()
       ->map(function ($clientTemp) {
        return [
            'id' => $clientTemp->id,
            'hash' => $clientTemp->hash,
            'name' => $clientTemp->first_name.' '.$clientTemp->last_name,
            'email' => $clientTemp->email,
            'mobile' => $clientTemp->mobile
        ];
    });
```

I am getting this data from two tables :

`1. Qutoations` and `2. Clients`.

In quotations table if the exp_date is less than current date then the details will be fetched from `client table`.

But there is possibility then there are more than 1 rows in quotation table but I want to fetch only one table from that for which customer_id is unique. How can I fetch unique row with same customer_id from quotations table

Comment: Are you even using any columns from the quotations table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use a GROUP BY clause but due to MySQL's default ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode, you must aggregate any column that has more than one value.

You don't seem to be actually using any values from quotations, so you could just add:

```
DB::table('clients')->select('clients.*')->groupBy('clients.id')...
```

Otherwise, you'd need to tell MySQL how to aggregate any rows that have multiple values, like:

```
DB::table('clients')->selectRaw('clients.*, MIN(quotations.id)')->groupBy('clients.id')...
```

Comment: return $datatables->collection($clientTemp)

            ->addColumn('actions', '@if(Sentinel::inRole(\'admin\'))
                                    <a href="{{ url(\'client/create/\' . $id) }}" title="{{ trans(\'table.edit\') }}">
                                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil text-warning "></i> </a>
                                    @endif')

            ->removeColumn('id')
            ->rawColumns(['actions'])->make();
} In addColumn, How can I add `client_id` instead of $id

Answer (score 1):

You should use groupby

```
$cur_date = date('Y-m-d');    $clientTemp = DB::table('clients')->where('quotations.exp_date','<',$cur_date)
     ->join('quotations','quotations.customer_id','=','clients.id')
     ->->groupBy('quotations.customer_id')
      ->get()
       ->map(function ($clientTemp) {
        return [
            'id' => $clientTemp->id,
            'hash' => $clientTemp->hash,
            'name' => $clientTemp->first_name.' '.$clientTemp->last_name,
            'email' => $clientTemp->email,
            'mobile' => $clientTemp->mobile
        ];
    });
```

Comment: It is throwing error :SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #36 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'billing.quotations.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `clients` inner join `quotations` on `quotations`.`customer_id` = `clients`.`id` where `quotations`.`exp_date` < 2018-08-25 group by `customer_id`)